# Access DAO Passthrough query - Access appends a semicolon to the SQL

Tags: ms-access, odbc, ms-access-2010

I have the following simple function to run an SQL passthrough query with ODBC:

```
Sub RunSQL(strSQL As String, DSN As String)

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qd As DAO.QueryDef
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
On Error Resume Next
db.QueryDefs.Delete "temp"
On Error GoTo 0
Set qd = db.CreateQueryDef("temp")
qd.Connect = "ODBC;DSN=" & DSN
qd.SQL = strSQL
qd.ODBCTimeout = 999
qd.ReturnsRecords = True
On Error GoTo Handler
Set rs = qd.OpenRecordset
Debug.Print rst!IALITM

db.QueryDefs.Delete "temp"
Exit Sub
Handler:
    Dim dbeError As Error
    For Each dbeError In DBEngine.Errors
        Debug.Print "(" & dbeError.Number & "): " & dbeError.Description
        Next
End Sub
```

The issue I'm having is that when I set the SQL, access automatically appends a semicolon to it as if using Access SQL syntax - the ODBC data source doesn't like this and returns an error. Is there any way I can stop Access from adding the ';', or remove it afterwards?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue using ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server. The [ODBC trace](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Troubleshooting-%E2%80%93-Generating-an-ODBC-trace-log) shows that Access is sending the query without appending a semicolon to the end: `"SELECT * from dbo.team\ 0"`. What ODBC driver are you using, and what is the actual error message that it returns?

Comment: @GordThompson strangely enough when I tried it today the issue didn't occur. I was previously getting a "token ; not expected" error, and if I `debug.print`ed the qd.SQL there would be the semicolon - very odd.